# Wait for service to start - while loop

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to improve my code to handle a service not starting. Consider this simple code:

```
while ((Get-Service $service).Status -eq 'Stopped') 
{
    Start-Service $service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose:$false
}
```

If there is a problem starting the service, I see `WARNING: Waiting for service '...' to Start...` 2-3 times, then it starts usually. My problem is when the service **will not start** due to error, the `while` is stuck in an infinite loop.

Is there a better way to handle this, and avoid the infinite loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to start a service and wait for a specified amount of time for it to start. It returns 0 if the service started successfully, or an error code if 1) the service doesn't exist, 2) the service is already running, or 3) the code timed out waiting for the service to start.

```
$ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 1053
$ERROR_SERVICE_ALREADY_RUNNING = 1056
$ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST  = 1060

function Start-Service {
  param(
    [String] $serviceName,
    [Int32] $timeoutSeconds
  )
  $service = Get-Service $serviceName
  if ( -not $service ) {
    return $ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
  }
  if ( $service.Status -eq [ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Running ) {
    return $ERROR_SERVICE_ALREADY_RUNNING
  }
  $timeSpan = New-Object Timespan 0,0,$timeoutSeconds
  try {
    $service.Start()
    $service.WaitForStatus([ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Running, $timeSpan)
    return 0
  }
  catch [Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException],[ServiceProcess.TimeoutException] {
    return $ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT
  }
}
```